# Как разбить имеющуюся строку по точкам, но при этом затронуть не все точки?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Разделяю определённые строки на массив точкой, но столкнулся с тем, что в этой строке может быть такая запись: "190601.65 Автомобили и автомобильное хозяйство. 38.04.04. Государственное и муниципальное управление". Что я сделал:

```
string[] separator = new string[] { ". " };
string[] prepEmpQual = elementEmpQual.InnerText.Trim().Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

В итоге получается массив с такими элементами:

190601.65 Автомобили и автомобильное хозяйство

38.04.04

Государственное и муниципальное управление

Последние два элемента не должны делиться, а быть одним (38.04.04. Государственное и муниципальное управление), как это возможно сделать?

Comment: А как. по какому критерию, отличать-то? И там, и там точка с пробелом... расширяйте критерий.

Comment: Регулярным выражением, `Regex.Split(elementEmpQual, @"(?<!\d\.\d+\.\d+)\.\s+")`? https://ideone.com/BpJ239

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew работает как нужно, благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Затем можно использовать

```
var result = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<!\d\.\d+\.\d+)\.\s+");
```

Результат:

```
90601.65 Автомобили и автомобильное хозяйство
38.04.04. Государственное и муниципальное управление
```

Регулярное выражение `(?<!\d\.\d+\.\d+)\.\s+` находит все вхождения точки (`.`) и следующих за ней одного и более пробельных символов (`\s+`), если сразу перед точкой нет `цифры.1+цифр.1+цифр`.

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/BpJ239)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно максимум два элемента при разделении, то можно использовать метод [`Split(string[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_):

```
string[] prepEmpQual = elementEmpQual.InnerText.Trim().Split(separator, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```